# Seeing error message from network tab, but not in the try/catch console.log(error)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, frontend

I am working on the front-end part of a project, and the backend is done, basically when a condition is met, the backend will send 409 conflict and a specific error message, and my job is to capture that error message and let that to be displayed on the front-end.

But I couldn't get the error message in the try-catch block, and only seeing the error message in the Network tab of Chrome.

Here's my try-catch front end code

```
try{
            const response = await this.request({
                path: `/api/xxx/xxx/{xxx}/xx`.replace(`{${"xxx"}}`, xx(String(requestParameters.terminalId))),
                method: 'PUT',
                headers: headerParameters,
                query: queryParameters,
                body: UpdateTerminalDataPortRequestDtoToJSON(requestParameters.updateTerminalDataPortRequestDto),
            }, initOverrides);
        }
        catch(e){
            console.log("error message")
            console.error(e)
        }
```

and here is what the Network Tab
[image]

and here is what the console log error look like:
[image]

How can I get the same error message as the one showing in the Networks?

Thanks in advance....any comment would be appreciated

Comment: Try to put `console.log("request resolved")` after `this.request(...)` method call. If it will show up and 409 is supposed to throw error, then you doesn't handle HTTP response codes correctly (f.e native [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) resolves all HTTP codes)

Comment: Have u solved it already? if so, let me know how did u resolve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it by accessing err.response through catch

```
.catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err.response)
})
```